# Is there a way I can use my usb flash drive or other storage device as RAM for running R or other programming tasks?

Tags: linux, r, flash, storage

I recently read an article online about how you can set up your flash drive unit to act as RAM. I usually have tasks in R that require some heavy-duty computing power and memory requirements. I have currently been using a linux redhat amazon machine image server online with a RAM of around 244 GB.

This got me thinking about if I can use a flash drive formatted primarily for RAM to be used for an R program on my home computer? In other words, is there a way to "tell" the R program on my computer to take advantage of the usb flash drive I have (USB 3.0 with 256 GB storage space)? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Using a USB stick as swap is covered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/173676/how-to-make-a-usb-stick-swap-disk

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to here, is called `swapping`.  `swapping` is using disk space (albeit a flash memory drive in this case) as RAM.  It's possible to do in most operating systems, but keep in mind that reading/writing to flash memory will be much slower (an order of magnitude or more) than reading/writing to RAM.